Scripting Bash genera 2 errores con el comando "find"
Muy buenas todos comunidad:
Estoy aprendiendo Bash Scripting y en mi intento de ir un paso más allá me he topado con un stderror, les comento desde el principio, he creado en mi directorio de trabajo 5 archivos llamados archivo_{1..5}, deseo buscar esos archivos he irlos depurando hasta solo obtener la columna de los números, cuando ejecuto los comandos desde la terminal funciona muy bien, pero cuando incluyo esa linea dentro del Script empiezan los problemas:



Bien, acudo a la comunidad para ver la posibilidad de que algún miembro con experiencia en el tema logre ver algo que yo no, ojo que he intentado enviar el argumento o criterio al bash Scripting con comillas, sin comillas, al revéz y al derecho, y no logro solución.
Muchas gracias

Añade comillas alrededor de $1 incluso en el script. : find . -name "$1" | ...

Hola Arnaud, muchas gracias por tu atención, hice lo que recomendaste ahora ya no da error pero no muestra nada, después de la ejecución solo presenta el prompt del sistema, pasa algo así como si lo enviara al "/dev/null"

El directorio actual (muy importante, ya que puede buscarlo con el comando find .) :
> ls
archivo_1
archivo_2
archivo_3
archivo_4
archivo_5
ej.sh

Línea de terminal Bash :
> find . -name "archivo_*" | sort | tr "_" " " | awk '{print $2}'
1
2
3
4
5

Con el script bash ej.sh :
#! /usr/bin/env bash

find . -name "$1" | sort | tr "_" " " | awk '{print $2}'


#! /usr/bin/env bash : «shebang» debe aparecer en la primera línea del script. Se utiliza para especificar el shell que se va a utilizar.
find . : Buscar en el directorio actual
-name "*" : Un fichero, directorio, etc. con el nombre/motivo dado

Las comillas son necesarias para proteger el contenido de la cadena $1 de ser reemplazado por el shell bash. El comando find buscará el patrón, usando bash.



Y que sea ejecutable:
chmod +x ./ej.sh

Invocando ej.sh :
> ./ej.sh "archivo*"
1
2
3
4
5


Ok, Ok, gracias por el detalle del "shebang", importante.

Como te explicó Arnaud, el problema básico es la falta de comillas en find . -name $1. Dado que $1 es "archivo*", tu comando se convierte en
find . -name archivo*

Ahora, el shell va a expandir el glob archivo* a archivo_1 archivo_2 archivo_3 archivo_4 archivo_5 convirtiendo tu comando a:
find . -name archivo_1 archivo_2 archivo_3 archivo_4 archivo_5

Y por esto tienes el error. La solución es meter la variable en comillas. Y, en general, siempre usar comillas a menos que sabes que no son necesarias (cosa bastante rara). La falta de comillas es probablemente el error mas común en el mundo del bash. Aquí tienes una explicación detallada de porque es importante (en ingles, lo siento): Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells.
Tu comando funcionará con la corrección previa, pero se puede también simplificar. Le puedes decir al awk de usar _ como separador, en vez de :
$ find . -name "archivo*" | awk -F"_" '{print $2}' | sort
1
2
3
4
5

O puedes usar cut:
$ find . -name "archivo*" | cut -d_ -f2 | sort
1
2
3
4
5

También podrías hacerlo todo en bash sin herramientas externas (asumiendo que todos los archivos están en el mismo directorio):
for file in archivo*; do
  printf '%s\n' "${file##*_}"
done

El formato ${variable##padrón} significa "elimina la coincidencia más larga de padrón del principio de variable". Por ejemplo:
$ var="foofoobar"
$ echo "${var##*foo}"
bar

Aquí, el padrón es *foo, o sea "cualquier cosa hasta un foo", entonces se quita el foofoo. En tu caso, el padrón es *_, y entonces se quita todo hasta el último _, dejándote con el número solo.

Una buena opción, voy a probar, gracias

Estoy pensado en voz alta y veo en el script el comando "awk" en sus argumentos existe un "print $2", podrá eso influenciar como que el script espera algún parámetro adicional ??, no se, podrá ser ?? y si es así como lo soluciono.

Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.

"$2" en awk significa: el valor de la segunda columna de la línea actual
